# selenium IDE - how to switch to a new window with a different URL?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

My application has a form that when submitted, then opens up a new window with a different URL.

Is there any way to get the selenium IDE to "use" that window?

I've tried a variety of open, openWindow, etc.  The main problem for me seems to be that this is not a 'javascript pop-up window' that I need to switch to, it is actually a new browser window with a different url and that window is the one I want to switch to.

For open, selenium says *"Opens an URL in the test frame. This accepts both relative and absolute URLs. The "open" command waits for the page to load before proceeding, ie. the "AndWait" suffix is implicit. Note: The URL must be on the same domain as the runner HTML due to security restrictions in the browser (Same Origin Policy). If you need to open an URL on another domain, use the Selenium Server to start a new browser session on that domain."*

ok, but how do I do that in the context of writing scripts in the selenium IDE

Answer (score 0):

If the form opens the new window automatically when you submit the form, the command you want is 'selectWindow' with the target as the window title.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to click on a link that launches a separate window, you must first instruct Selenium IDE to select that window first before you could access the elements within it. To do this, you will use the window's title as its locator.

Use selectWindow command in switching between windows.